# How to get statistical distributions out of C++ Code?

Tags: c++, statistics

I want some help in programming a random generator for different types of distribution using C++ language. for the following:

- Geometric distribution
- Hypergeometric distribution
- Weibull distribution
- Rayleigh distribution
- Erlang distribution
- Gamma distribution
- Poisson distribution

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Boost Random Number library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/random/index.html) is very good. There's a simple example of how its distributions work at [Boost random number generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254909/boost-random-number-generator).

Answer (score 2):

[Boost Math](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/dist/dist_ref/dists.html) Library contains all of that you need.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to avoid the big size of boost, you can try AlgLib www.alglib.net

Comment: Thank you all guys. I really appreciate it.

Good luck.

Best Regards,