# Cross-OS distributed computing in C++, rand() issue

Tags: c++, random, distributed-computing, srand

I'm working on a small distributed computing project. The server can't handle the calculations without crashing Apache in the process, so I'm giving these calculations to the users.

The basic idea is that I run the calculations 3 times, and the results need to be exactly the same. However, the application will need to run on Mac, Linux and Windows. Basically this means that I can't use rand().

I'm probably looking for a replacement generator which accepts a seed value (provided by the server) and gives the same results on every platform.

My question is: is that indeed what I am looking for and do you have a good recommendation, or should I be doing this in a different way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the [Boost.Random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_random.html) facilities. They give you a broad choice of algorithms that are guaranteed to give the same results, always.

Comment: +1 for being faster than me. ;-) But yes, I believe Boost.Random will give portable results across different platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Write your own.  It's surprisingly straightforward.

"Numerical Recipes in C - The Art of Scientific Computing" has several algorithms, and I can present you just one (“Minimal” random number generator of Park and Miller.) :

```
#define IA 16807
#define IM 2147483647
#define AM (1.0/IM)
#define IQ 127773
#define IR 2836
#define MASK 123459876



float ran0(long *idum)
{
 long k;
 float ans;
 *idum ^= MASK;
 k=(*idum)/IQ;
 *idum=IA*(*idum-k*IQ)-IR*k;
 if (*idum < 0) *idum += IM;
  ans=AM*(*idum);
 *idum ^= MASK;
 return ans;
}
```

Returns a uniform random deviate between 0.0 and 1.0. Set or reset idum to any integer value (except the unlikely value MASK) to initialize the sequence; idum must not be altered between calls for successive deviates in a sequence.

**EDIT**

Since you need good performances for a RNG, you can use a quick and dirty algorithm. Here is one :

```
unsigned long idum; // initialize the value to something
// get a RND
idum = 1664525L*idum + 1013904223L;
```

Comment: Its both surprisingly straightforward, and surprisingly easy to get wrong.

Comment: Looks good and I assume that the performance of this code is pretty good as well. However I'll just be honest and say that I have absolutely no idea what happens in the code above and until I do I'm probably sticking with Boost. Of course, if I get performance issues I'll make sure to consider this code :) +1 for showing me how "easy" it is.

Comment: @Tom Off course there are other algorithms in the book, but I doubt you will have performance problems with the boost library

Comment: @VJo I think that more than a third of all calculations done is related to random numbers. The actual bottleneck of the application will, of course, be the speed of the RAM, but I want to optimize wherever I can. For now, however, I'm going for simplicity.

Comment: @Tom In that case, you can a quick and dirty RNG

Answer (score 0):

The boost random number library is very good - there's an example of its use here [Boost random number generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254909/boost-random-number-generator). As far as I'm aware, its implementations produce the same results cross platform, but I've never tested this.