# Generate random numbers in C++-11 in different parts of a code using the same seed

Tags: c++, c++11, random, random-seed

I am trying to encapsulate a class to generate random numbers controlling by seed and by the range of random values. I want to call this class from different parts of my codes, with different ranges, but using the same seed.

Following suggestions of other post ([Encapsulated Random number generator in C++-11 using boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31417957/encapsulated-random-number-generator-in-c-11-using-boost)) I implemented the following code:

My Random Number Generator class:

```
    #include <random>
    #include <iostream>

    typedef std::mt19937                     ENG;    // Mersenne Twister
    typedef std::uniform_int_distribution<> iDIST;   // Uniform Integer Distribution

    class RNG {
      private:
         ENG eng;
         iDIST idist;

      public:
         iDIST::result_type igen() { return idist(eng); }
         RNG(ENG eng_,int imin,int imax)
         : idist(imin,imax)
         {eng = eng_; }

    };
```

A function to create an object of RNG class and print the random values:

```
    void myfunc(ENG eng_,int imin, int imax, int N){
        RNG myirn(eng_,imin,imax);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            std::cout << myirn.igen() << std::endl;
        }
        return;
    }
```

My main function:

```
    int main(int argc, char **argv){
        int myseed = 1;
        int N = 5;
        int imin1 = 1;
        int imax1 = 10;

    //Seed globally
        ENG eng_;
        eng_.seed(myseed);

        std::cout << "Range = [" << imin1 << "," << imax1 << "]" << std::endl;
        myfunc(eng_,imin1,imax1,N);
        std::cout << "Range = [" << imin1 << "," << imax1 << "]" << std::endl;
        myfunc(eng_,imin1,imax1,N);


    return 0;
    }
```

As you can see, my strategy was to seed my random number generator globally (in the main function) and pass the variable eng_ as a parameter to the function func, that will instantiate the RNG object and print the random values. If everything were correct, this code should print 2 sequences of 5 random numbers within the same range but with different values. However, they are exactly the same sequence. Could anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: You're passing ENG by value and not by reference.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @Svalorzen. Could you please be more specific? In my main function I pass an ENG object to myfunc. And in myfunc I pass an ENG object to the RNG constructor. Did you change the code and had a good result (two different sequences of 5 random values within the same range)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you want to use the same engine, you have to use the same engine.  (That much is a singleton.)  Pass a reference to RNG, store and use a reference within RNG.  Minor changes to your code make this so (one of the comments already pointed this out):

```
ENG &eng;
RNG(ENG &eng_, int imin, int imax)
    : idist(imin, imax), eng(eng_) {}

void myfunc(ENG &eng_, int imin, int imax, int N)
```

But I like it better if the engine is hidden in RNG like this:

```
class RNG {
private:
    static ENG eng;
    iDIST idist;
public:
    static void seed(int s) { eng.seed(s); }
    RNG(int imin, int imax) : idist(imin, imax) {}
    int generate() { return idist(eng); }
};

// the one generator, stored as RNG::eng
ENG RNG::eng;

// print some generated numbers from a range
void printRandomNumbers(int imin, int imax, int N){
    std::cout << "Range = [" << imin << "," << imax << "]" << std::endl;
    RNG myirn(imin, imax);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        std::cout << myirn.generate() << std::endl;
    }
    return;
}

int main()
{
    //Seed globally
    int myseed = 1;
    RNG::seed(myseed);
    printRandomNumbers(1, 10, 5);
    printRandomNumbers(11, 20, 5);
    printRandomNumbers(21, 30, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: looking at the code, I see how easy it is to accidentally pass it by value in one place and mess everything up.  I'm going to see what happens when I make the seed and engine class static inside RNG.

Comment: Exactly, @KennyOstrom. You got exactly what I want to do. I want to be able to inject a new range if I need. Your suggestion worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: I accepted your answer because it was clear and did exactly what I needed to do. But, of course, any improvement is very welcome, it will not change my vote.

Comment: Amazing! It seems to be a better option when I need to split the functions into many files. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Singleton Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

> In software engineering, the singleton pattern is a design pattern
>   that restricts the instantiation of a class to one object. This is
>   useful when exactly one object is needed to coordinate actions across
>   the system. The concept is sometimes generalized to systems that
>   operate more efficiently when only one object exists, or that restrict
>   the instantiation to a certain number of objects. The term comes from
>   the mathematical concept of a singleton.

```
class RandomGenerator
{
    public:
        static RandomGenerator& get_instance( void )
        {
            static RandomGenerator instance;
            return instance;
        }

    private:
        RandomGenerator() { /*seed generator*/ };

        RandomGenerator( RandomGenerator const& ) = delete;
        void operator=( RandomGenerator const& ) = delete;
};
```

**Alternatively**

[Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

> In software engineering, dependency injection is a software design
>   pattern that implements inversion of control for resolving
>   dependencies. An injection is the passing of a dependency (a service
>   or software module) to a dependent object (a client). The service is
>   made part of the client's state. Passing the service to the client,
>   rather than allowing a client to build or find the service, is the
>   fundamental requirement of the pattern.

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        void set_random_generator( const RandomGenerator& value );
}
```

Comment: That was my first thought, but he specifically wants different ranges, but coming from the same engine.

Comment: He might be able to inject a new range as needed, but I think it's safer and easier to keep the engine as the singleton, like he originally posted, and just make a new RNG for each separate range.